# SproutCore: Setting up proxy in Buildfile doesn't work

Tags: javascript, database, web-applications, proxy, sproutcore

I added the following line  in my buildfile:
`proxy "/tasks", :to => "localhost:3000"`

Yet, the error I get is `GET http://localhost:4020/tasks 404 (Not Found)`.
Which means, the proxy setup hasn't been effected. 
Where am I going wrong?

Here's the buildfile:

```
config :todos, :required => :sproutcore
proxy "/tasks", :to => 'localhost:3000'
```

Note: I tried restarting the server too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by adding the line to the Project  Buildfile instead of the App Buildfile.